# OpenLayer Static Image Size

Tags: zooming, openlayers-3

I am using Openlayer version 3 for some mapping process. My map source is static image for this reason I used ol.source.ImageStatic datasource type.

My problem is zoom level. How can find zoom level to show image actual size? When load high definition image, OpenLayer show it smaller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Map resolution/zoom can be listen with:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt){
    var resolution = evt.target.get(evt.key);
    console.info(resolution);

});
```

You can also monitor your [`ol.layer.Image`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Image.html)

```
your_image_layer.on('change:maxResolution', function(evt){


});
your_image_layer.on('change:minResolution', function(evt){


});
```